# How to enable SSH access from a server outside my network?

Tags: centos, ssh, port-forwarding

I have a computer A (CentOS 7) in my local network and a website B hosted outside my local network. I need to enable SSH access from B to A (I intend to use phpseclib to transfer files between them). I configured A to have a static IP address 192.168.0.201.

I tried using my router configuration interface to make A into a Virtual Server, as follows: [Virtual Server config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NGSQe.png). My intent is that when I SSH to my public IP address and one specific port, to get redirected to computer A.

Then I tried to use PuTTy from another PC on my local network to connect to A using my public IP address and port 21, but got timed out. I was not sure about the protocol and port so I also tried to config the Virtual Server Service Type as SSH and port 22, but got timed out again.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the, the port you need is 22 as this is the port of SSH and it seems like you configured your router properly.
Port 21 is the default FTP protocol port.

Then, I’d check your centos server iptables status, as by default it is turned on and blocking all incoming connections.

Just for the test, I’d shut the service down and try reconnecting.

You do that by running:

```
systemctl stop iptables
```

If you see that you are now able to connect from the outside then restart iptables and set a rule to open port 22 specifically like so:

```
iptables -A INPUT -i NIC_NAME -p tcp —dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```